# In git merge, after the conflict occurs, how to view git diff in Visual Studio Code and keep the line number unchanged?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

If I just change the text of the same file in a branch, then use the command `git difftool` to get this effect:
[image]

However, if I use the merge command and get the conflict, then use the `git difftool` command, it won't have this effect but only get the effect of the third image and the text of normal `git diff` command.

If I use the compare function built-in with Visual Studio Code, it can't keep the original line number unchanged:
[image]

I hope that is the effect:
[image]

Comment: And you r question is...?

Answer (score 0):

I find this feature, open the key bindings with `Command+ Shirft+P` in macOS, and then enter `Merge Conflict: Compare Current Conflict`:
[image]
[image]